# column with value as Concatenate other columns' value

Tags: sql-server-2008, constraints

In Below Table, I want `full_name` column to take Default value as concatenation of values in `first_name`, `middle_name` & `last_name` columns.

### SQL Table

```
CREATE TABLE ms_employee
(
    emp_no int unique,
    first_name varchar(100) not null,
    middle_name varchar(100) not null,
    last_name varchar(100) not null,
    full_name varchar(100)  
)
```

### Code

*code below gives error*

```
ALTER TABLE ms_employee ADD CONSTRAINT [cons_1] DEFAULT ([first_name]+' '+[middle_name]+' '+[last_name]) FOR [emp_name]
```

### Error Message

```
The name "first_name" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
```

So, it's not working using `Constraint`!

How to achieve it, using `Constraint`? OR any other way will also be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it to a [Computed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) column.

```
ALTER TABLE ms_employee DROP COLUMN [full_name];

GO

ALTER TABLE ms_employee ADD [full_name]  
       AS ([first_name] + ' ' + [middle_name] + ' ' + [last_name])
```

Comment: Great!!! Got exact problem, It takes concatenation of other columns & also Explicit Insert in it is NOT ALLOWED. Thank You!